# How do i create a shiny center gradient overlay for my modal in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I would like to ask if you guys encountered how to create
a circular shiny gradient for a modal overlay. The effect is causing viewer to be more aware and focus on the modal. That is why i like it to be used.

[image]

Comment: Please read the wiki page for [tag:design-patterns]. It is not applicable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use gradient editor at: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ . select radial Orientation. edit color as desired and add the style to modal-backdrop class as below:

```
.modal-backdrop {
    background: rgb(181,189,200); /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%, rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%, rgba(40,52,59,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(181,189,200,1)), color-stop(36%,rgba(130,140,149,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(40,52,59,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(40,52,59,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(40,52,59,1) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(40,52,59,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(40,52,59,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b5bdc8', endColorstr='#28343b',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

Also, give box shadow http://css3generator.com/ to `.modal` class if needed.

```
.modal {
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -moz-box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply target the modal-backdrop class. I pulled out a demo gradient CSS using an online CSS generator. Try it out based on how you want the gradient effect to be

```
.modal-backdrop {
    background: rgb(235,233,249); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(235,233,249,1) 0%, rgba(216,208,239,1) 50%, rgba(206,199,236,1) 51%, rgba(193,191,234,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(235,233,249,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(216,208,239,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(206,199,236,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(193,191,234,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(235,233,249,1) 0%,rgba(216,208,239,1) 50%,rgba(206,199,236,1) 51%,rgba(193,191,234,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(235,233,249,1) 0%,rgba(216,208,239,1) 50%,rgba(206,199,236,1) 51%,rgba(193,191,234,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(235,233,249,1) 0%,rgba(216,208,239,1) 50%,rgba(206,199,236,1) 51%,rgba(193,191,234,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(235,233,249,1) 0%,rgba(216,208,239,1) 50%,rgba(206,199,236,1) 51%,rgba(193,191,234,1) 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

Comment: Clannad System is asking center to corner gradient not top to bottom.